# Is it correct to say "My company rented a car from Abc" when my company wanted to use the car for several years?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage

Now, if we know that we just want to pay money for the use of a car for *a short time* (2 or 3 days or weeks), then

The British will say: "My company **hired** a car from Abc"
Americans will say: "My company **rented** a car from Abc"

Now my company wanted to use the car for several years, then do we use "**rent**" or "**lease**"?

According to my study, if you pay money for the use of some property **for a long time**, then you can use "*rent*" or "*lease*". For example,

> "*My company **rented** a house from Abc*" or "*My company **leased** a house from Abc*".

However, if you pay money for the use of some equipment for a long time, then you can use "*lease*" only. For example,

> "*My company leased a car from Abc*" and we can not say
> "*My company rented a car from Abc*" in this particular situation.

Is that correct?

Comment: It may depend on what variety of English you are using.  Here in the UK long term car hire is generally called leasing.  You can say the car is leased from [a company], or the car is on lease from [a company], or it's a leased car.  We don't usually call house rental "leasing", but "house letting" is definitely a thing.  You will often see "for let" signs on houses/flats for rent. I don't know how Americans refer to this. Sorry

Comment: @BillyKerr - agreed, and the 'long term' is usually 'longer than six months'.

Comment: In the US, it's quite common to use 'lease' for a contract for renting a residence for a long period.

Comment: In business contexts, in the US, we say leased for cars. Renting a car is short-term.

Comment: Strictly speaking leasing a car is a different type of contract than renting it. So whether you would say they rent it or lease it depends on whether they are actually, well, renting or leasing it.

Comment: As this is the corporate world which has to abide by rules for book-keeping: A long term lease contract has to be disclosed in the reports in many cases. Reasoning is that the contract stipulates future payments that cannot be waived. This should be shown to the share owners and financial markets. Distinct from a rent that has a short time to termination.

Comment: Correct? No, never for the simple reason that the Question is meaningless.

Your company is welcome to have rented a car, and to have wanted to use it forever.

That might interest lawyers or accountants but can you explain why the rest of us should care?

Whether to 'rent' or 'lease' is important but also wholly different and in no way related to the Question.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Are you saying the question of whether a particular English sentence is correct is meaningless?

Comment: No, Gotube. Of course not.

Where did you get that idea?

Comment: Sorry, Gotube; this isn't about English.

In English, it is perfectly acceptable to say 'My company rented a car from Abc" when your company wanted to use the car for several years.

What difficulties do you see, either in language or in any technicalities involved in car rental?

Answer (score 22):

In the US, *leasing* a car is quite different from *renting* a car.

> A car lease is a popular type of auto financing that allows you to “rent” a car from a dealership for a certain length of time and amount of miles. You’ll typically make monthly lease payments on a vehicle, and in exchange the dealer allows you to drive it. At the end of the lease, you’ll either return the vehicle to the dealership or buy out your lease if you want to keep the car, if that’s an option in your lease.

[Credit Karma](https://www.creditkarma.com/auto/i/what-is-car-leasing)

Some of the key differences that we can see in this description include:

- You *lease* a car from a **dealership*** (businesses that typically sell cars), whereas you *rent* a car from a **car rental agency** (businesses that typically only rent cars for relatively short periods)
- Leasing agreements typically have a defined end date, whereas rental deals can often be extended from month to month
- At the end of the lease, the lessee is typically given the opportunity to purchase the car
- As such, a leasing agreement is often more similar to an auto-loan than a car rental, in that it's either a path to, or an alternative to buying a car

Car rentals can be long-term - for example, Avis (a car rental agency) offers rentals up to 11 months, and leases can sometimes be rather short (though they are typically 2-4 years), so length of time isn't the best way to distinguish a rental agreement from a lease.  Avis lists some other differences between *renting* and *leasing* a car:

> What Do I Need to Lease a Car?
>
> - Driver’s license
> - An acceptable credit score (670+)
> - Proof of auto insurance
> - Proof of income/ability to pay

> What Do I Need to Rent a Car?
>
> - Driver’s license
> - Credit card
> - A clean driving record

[Avis](https://www.avis.com/en/help/usa-faqs/lease-vs-rent)

Again, the credit rating, proof of insurance, and proof of income make leasing a car far more similar to getting an auto loan.

So, whether your company "leased" or "rented" a car will not depend on the length of time, but on the type of contract.  And though the specific nature of the difference (as well as the other answer here suggesting that the terms can sometimes be used interchangeably) might suggest that only lawyers and snoots are careful about which word to use, I'd suggest this is not the case.

I would not expect to hear someone say, not even in casual conversation, "I rented a car from the Toyota dealership", nor "I leased a car from Avis".

---

*Really the lease is typically only arranged by the dealership; the financing comes from someone else.  Often financing can come from the automaker - for example, Ford Motor Credit, Ally, Honda Finance, etc. - which may have some relationship with, but is separate from the dealership [Consumer Reports](https://www.consumerreports.org/money/car-financing/how-to-get-the-best-car-lease-a5526450548/).

The main point here was that when you lease a car, the car is usually coming from a car dealership, not a rental agency.

Comment: This is a great answer but I would suggest a couple of minor improvements for the sake of accuracy: 1. a "lessee" (not a "leaser") is the party that leases from a "lessor."  2. Customers who lease cars typically lease them from a finance company, not from the car dealership.  These finance companies are often but not always owned by the vehicle manufacturers, which means the car company's leasing arm buys the vehicle back from the dealership then leases it to the customer.

Comment: @MattMorgan, done - sort of.  The information about lease financing is only stapled on.  If you can think of a better way to integrate it into the answer, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

In the UK  "**lease**" tends to mean only for longer periods. You lease a car or a property for a number of months or years.
"**rent**" can be any length of time from an hour (or less) up to years. You can rent a power tool for the morning or rent your house for many years.
However "**the rent**" is the money you pay per period of time (week / month / year) whilst "**a lease**" is the legal contract you sign with your landlord defining the terms of your tenancy, although this could also be called "a rental agreement". So there is considerable overlap in their use.
As a point of interest, a "peppercorn rent" is a nominal, usually anual, sum paid. For example by a leaseholder to the freeholder where no significant ground rent is charged.
Not being a lawyer there may well be some legal definitions that distinguish between them and this may differ from country to country.

Answer (score 1):

Renting and leasing are legally different things. You would most likely use the word that reflects the reality.

Now it’s a a fact that car leasing contracts are usually over years, while renting a car is usually done for some months at most. So if you use “rent” for two weeks and “lease” for a year, that is most likely factually correct.

For a home, you often use “rent” for private persons renting the place they live, and “lease” for companies renting office space. There will also be differences between private persons and companies renting.